# setvbuf behavior different in VS 2015

Tags: c, visual-studio-2015

I wanted to move up from Visual Studio 2013 to Visual Studio 2015, but I ran into this odd behavior when I converted some of my code.  The following code works fine in VS 2013. It also works if I comment out the setvbuf() command.  But when I run this code in VS 2015, fgets() keeps accumulating input until I enter an even number of characters.  Is this behavior a bug, or is there something I'm missing?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    setvbuf(stdin, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
    char buf[256];

    printf("Waiting for input\n");
    fgets(buf, 80, stdin);

    printf("received %s\n", buf);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I see it.  Looks like a pretty structural bug, without a buffer it reads from the console with a 2-byte buffer.  That causes the \n to get swallowed.if it is the 2nd character.  Post this bug at connect.microsoft.com

Comment: Thanks. I've posted it there.